# Linq to Entities over EF 4 on SQL Server 2005

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

> 'Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1'. Only primitive types (such as Int32, String, and Guid) and entity types are supported.'

Entities & Relationships (Navigation Properties):

```
Case (1 <-> ∞) MeetingCase (1 <-> ∞) MeetingCaseOutcomes
```

The offending code is:

```
IQueryable<Case> cases; // this is obviously attached to a context and able to access data)
var broken = cases
   .Where(c => c.MeetingCases
      .Where(mc => mc.ExpectedStartDateTime <= DateTime.Now)
         .Any(m => m.MeetingCaseOutcomes == null || m.MeetingCaseOutcomes.Count == 0));
```

I assume the problem is due to lack of support for the 'Any' operator, though I had thought this would work in EF 4 (since support for the related 'Contains' operator has been added).

How should I re-structure this call to produce what I want?

I have been working with EF for several months now and understand many of the runtime gotchas

**UPDATE:**

The Where clause above does contain a predicate, as follows:

```
c.MeetingCases.Where(mc => mc.ExpectedStartDateTime <= DateTime.Now)
              .Any(m => m.MeetingCaseOutcomes == null || m.MeetingCaseOutcomes.Count == 0)
```

Because `Any` returns a boolean, the whole thing produces a predicate expression.

Also, the intent of this logic is to return a set of Case objects which do not have MeetingCaseOutcome records for any MeetingCase records where the meeting has already taken place (hence the comparison to DateTime.Now). This is part of a meeting scheduling system, and this is to check that Outcomes from each meeting are entered into the system following the meeting taking place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF 1 and EF 4 both support `.Any()`. The problem is that you're not using it enough. :)

```
IQueryable<Case> cases; // this is obviously attached to a context and able to access data)
var broken = cases
   .Where(c => c.MeetingCases
                .Where(mc => mc.ExpectedStartDateTime <= DateTime.Now)
                .Any(m => !m.MeetingCaseOutcomes.Any()));
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick, though semantically it seems to convey the same intent as what I had. Now I can ditch the stored proc I'd replaced it with :)

Answer (score 1):

This part is the problem:

```
Where(c => c.MeetingCases
      .Where..
```

`.Where` requires a `Expression<Func<T,bool>>`, in otherwords a predicate which returns true/false. But your supplying it a predicate which returns a **sequence** of elements.

I think that second `.Where` needs to be changed to `.Any` or `.All`.

I'm struggling to decipher what query your attempting to execute, but i'm assuming you want a list of `Case` where at least one associated `MeetingCase` has a `ExpectedStartDateTime` before today.

So your query should be:

```
var cases = cases
   .Where(case => case.MeetingCases
      .Any(caseMeeting => caseMeeting.ExpectedStartDateTime <= DateTime.Now));
```

I'm not sure what your trying to do with that last `.Any` clause.

Also - don't forget about eager-loading/projection problems. You say "it's attached to the context", which is fine - but `c.MeetingCases` will not return anything unless you have lazy loading on or are eager loading beforehand.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply RPM!

The given code is extracted out of a larger block, though I will include that block verbatim to give you the full picture:

Comment: Ok, I'll have to strip it down a little due to size constraints, but here is more complete section: